# how random questions with array android? no work

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-layout

> Blockquote

Excuse me, i want to ask i have a case of wanting random quiz using array but can not randomize every problem, only one problem is changed, maybe there can be help and solution friend
enter code here

private int pertanyaan[] ={R.raw.correct, R.raw.wrong,
R.raw.correct, R.raw.wrong, R.raw.correct, R.raw.wrong, R.raw.correct,R.raw.wrong, R.raw.assalamu_alaikum, R.raw.correct};

```
  public String pilihanganda [] ={
          "Perhatikan gambar tersebut gambar ?, carilah seperti gambar diatas",
          "Perhatikan gambar tersebut gambar ?, carilah seperti gambar diatas",
          "Perhatikan gambar tersebut gambar ?, carilah seperti gambar diatas",
          "Perhatikan gambar tersebut gambar ?, carilah seperti gambar diatas",
          "Perhatikan gambar tersebut gambar ?, carilah seperti gambar diatas",
          "Perhatikan gambar tersebut gambar ?, carilah seperti gambar diatas",
          "Perhatikan gambar tersebut gambar ?, carilah seperti gambar diatas",
          "Perhatikan gambar tersebut gambar ?, carilah seperti gambar diatas",
          "Perhatikan gambar tersebut gambar ?, carilah seperti gambar diatas",
          "Perhatikan gambar tersebut gambar ?, carilah seperti gambar diatas",

          };



 private int pilihan_a [] ={R.drawable.hidung, R.drawable.wajah, R.drawable.rambut, R.drawable.pergelangan_kaki, 
                    R.drawable.telinga, R.drawable.rambut, R.drawable.leher, R.drawable.lengan, R.drawable.rambut
                    , R.drawable.telinga};
 private int pilihan_b[] ={R.drawable.tangan, R.drawable.rambut,R.drawable.leher, R.drawable.tangan, 
                    R.drawable.pergelangan_kaki, R.drawable.leher, R.drawable.rambut, R.drawable.lengan, R.drawable.telinga
                    , R.drawable.pundak};
 private  int pilihan_c[] ={R.drawable.pundak, R.drawable.lengan, R.drawable.tangan, R.drawable.pundak, R.drawable.pergelangan_kaki
                    , R.drawable.tangan, R.drawable.pergelangan_kaki, R.drawable.wajah, R.drawable.lengan,
                    R.drawable.rambut};
 private  int pilihan_d[] ={R.drawable.pergelangan_kaki, R.drawable.tangan, R.drawable.hidung, R.drawable.pundak, 
          R.drawable.rambut, R.drawable.pundak, R.drawable.tangan, R.drawable.leher, R.drawable.telinga, R.drawable.pergelangan_kaki};

 public static String [] jawaban ={"A","B","B","C","A","C","D","C","C","B"};

   @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.quiz_2);

            player = MediaPlayer.create(this, pertanyaan[indeks]);               
            soal = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button2);

            soal.setBackgroundResource(pertanyaan[indeks]);
            soal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                 public void onClick(View v) {
                     Log.v(TAG,"Playing Sound...");
                    player.start();

             }
             });

          soalnya = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Soal);
          soalnya.setText(pilihanganda[0]);

          player = MediaPlayer.create(this, pertanyaan[indeks]); 
          imgB=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.pilihan2);
          imgC=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.pilihan3);
          imgD=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.pilihan4);
          imgA=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.pilihan1);

          imgA.setImageResource(pilihan_a[indeks]);
          imgA.setOnClickListener(this);
          imgB.setImageResource(pilihan_b[indeks]);
          imgB.setOnClickListener(this);
          imgC.setImageResource(pilihan_c[indeks]);
          imgC.setOnClickListener(this);
          imgD.setImageResource(pilihan_d[indeks]);
          imgD.setOnClickListener(this);

          nomor = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.No);
          nomor.setText("Soal " + no++);

          salahbenar =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.salahbenar);
          salahbenar.setText("");

    }
```

Comment: what do you want to randomize all your string arrays??

Comment: Yes all strings and arrays, how to resolve them, still fail

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array questions[] or answers [], and you need x questions such as it may be 10, you can create a question list as  is:

```
   Random rand = new Random(); 
   int questionLength = 10;    //the number questions you will use
   int[] myList = new int[questionLength];    
   for (int i = 0; i < questionLength; i++) {
       myList[i] =  rand.nextInt( allQuestionlist.size() );
   }
```

this array will be your indexes of random questions such as :

```
   for (int i = 0; i < questionLength; i++) {
       System.out.println( pilihanganda[myList[i]]  ); // printing
   }
```

Comment: I want to ask for allQuestions what is it? I try to error, sorry still learning

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use some values from your String arrays then you can use the below answer but if you're going to use all the questions then try this:

To shuffle two arrays the same way:

```
private voice Integer [] question = {R.raw.bahu, R.raw.dagu, R.raw.rambut, R.raw.kaki, R.raw.mata, R.raw.telinga, R.raw.gigi, R.raw.wajah, R.raw.lidah, R.raw.hidung};
```

let's say the below array is your answer array

```
private int pilihan_a [] ={R.drawable.hidung, R.drawable.wajah, R.drawable.rambut, R.drawable.pergelangan_kaki, 
                    R.drawable.telinga, R.drawable.rambut, R.drawable.leher, R.drawable.lengan, R.drawable.rambut
                    , R.drawable.telinga};
```

then use this to shuffle these two arrays the same way:

```
    long seed = System.nanoTime();
    List<String> questionList = Arrays.asList(question);
    List<String> answerList = Arrays.asList(pilihan_a);
    Collections.shuffle(questionList, new Random(seed));
    Collections.shuffle(answerList, new Random(seed));

    //Now both question and answer array has randomly shuffled elements in it in the same way
    pilihan_a = answerList.toArray(new String[myList.size()]);
    question = questionList.toArray(new String[myList.size()]);
```

Hope it solves your problem.

Comment: I have tried but the problem and the multiple choice and the answer does not match what the outcome may be able to tell, my coding as above for the quiz, I have not found at all

Comment: My question is a private voice Integer [] question = {R.raw.bahu, R.raw.dagu,
              R.raw.rambut, R.raw.kaki, R.raw.mata, R.raw.telinga, R.raw.gigi,
              R.raw.wajah, R.raw.lidah, R.raw.hidung};

And answer options like array: Pilihan_a, Pilihan_b, Pilihan_c.pilihan_d,
How to make random like the coding I made